# Transferring Angry Birds from one computer to another computer

Tags: angry-birds, angry-birds-rio

I lost my redemption key code and I am now using another computer for now. How can I transfer my angry birds games to this computer without having to re-buy them?

Comment: Is this through the Intel store?

Answer (score 1):

Rovio customer service is available at [this link](http://www.rovio.com/en/support).  They may have some ability to help you.

In the future, you may want to start a little file folder with print outs of your product keys to make them easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here.  The first is your product key, which @Tharius addressed in his answer.  The other issue is that when you install Angry Birds on another computer or device you will lose your progress (unless you use Rovio Accounts and cloud sync, but this isn't available for all games/platforms).  You CAN transfer your Angry Birds progress though, you just have to be a bit proactive and create a backup.  Since every platform is different your best bet is to check http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-ultimate-backup-tutorial-for-all-platforms/.  It explains in detail how to backup and transfer your progress across multiple devices.